# hdf5: Reading a slice is much slower than a single index

Tags: python, performance, dataset, hdf5, h5py

I found out that reading a slice is much slower than reading a single index from a 3D dataset:

```
out = h5py.File("my_data.hdf5", "w")
dset = out.create_dataset("data", shape=(10000, 10, 5000), compression=None, dtype="float32")

%timeit dset[0]  # 277 µs
%timeit dset[0:100]  # 6.36 ms
```

I would expect the time difference to be much smaller since we are reading a continuous slice of data. I tried to use `chunks=(100, 10, 5000)` but it didn't help.

Is there a way to reduce the reading time of slices (maybe we could save the dset differently with chunks, use chunk caching etc.)?

Comment: `dset[0]` has 50000 elements, not a  trivial amount.  The slice is 100 times more, but the time is only 20x more.

Comment: Indeed it is faster than reading the elements one by one 100 times. But I was wondering if there is a way to speed it up, perhaps by saving the data in chunks somehow.

Comment: Yes, chunking may improve I/O performance. You have to set chunk size when you create the dataset. An entire chunk of data is always read, so optimum shape depends on how you plan to read data. Start with `chunks=yes` if you don't know a good size, then experiment with different shapes. Read h5py docs; they have more details.

Comment: @kcw78 I want to read data as 0:100, 100:200 etc, i.e. 100 images of size 10x5000 each time. I tried to set `chunks=(100, 10, 5000)` but didn't see any improvement.

Comment: Chunking behavior is not simple or obvious. As I recall, h5py docs suggest chunk size should be between 10KB and 1MB. Yours is 19MB for (100,10,5000) of float32. Did you test the default size? After that, try (5,10,5000).

Comment: Also, check out the `iter_chunks()` method. It returns an iterator to do chunk by chunk reads. Example: `for s in dset.iter_chunks():